# Preferred handling of apparent spam that otherwise meets SE criteria

Tags: discussion

I've recently come across several similar posts that have the "feel" of spam, but which are sufficiently outside the Stack Exchange [criteria for using the spam flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor). What is the preferred way to call (moderator?) attention to the posts? Downvoting? Use the spam flag anyway? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want ♦ moderator attention, there's a special flag for that. In fact, when it's not obviously spam, it's the preferred cause of action; there's [no way to add additional information to a spam flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251565/295232) and the ♦ moderators might not see why it's spam without that information.

[Downvoting is optional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302217/295232) but doesn't get any further attention to the post. You might leave a comment, e.g. linking to [this Help Center article](/help/promotion) in cases where the answer is on-topic but just doesn't meet our self-promotion criteria. Many new users are not familiar with the rules; many other Internet sites don't have such strict rules as we do. In those cases, I normally don't cast a flag; I hope my comment has the desired effect and that the user will become a good Stack Exchange citizen.